# How can I test my package with one function?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I made a package that compiles fine but when I try to test it it gives me "invalid data type".
I've tried two different ways, first one like this

```
select pkg_contabilidad.f_totalizar_Detalle(100) FROM DUAL;
```

It gives me the ORA-00902 'invalid data type'
Also I've tried this

```
DECLARE 
    TYPE r_registro IS RECORD
    (rubro_contable CN_RUBROS_CONTABLES.COD_RUBRO%TYPE,
    tipo VARCHAR2(1),
    monto NUMBER(16));
    resultao r_registro;
    numero NUMBER :=100;
BEGIN
    resultao := pkg_contabilidad.f_totalizar_detalle(numero);
END;
```

It gives me another error PLS-00382 'expression is of wrong type'
I don't know what am I doing wrong, cause my function receives just one parameter and is of type NUMBER, so I dont know where's my mistake. I'll leave the code of my package just in case

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_contabilidad AS
TYPE r_registro IS RECORD
(rubro_contable CN_RUBROS_CONTABLES.COD_RUBRO%TYPE,
tipo VARCHAR2(1),
monto NUMBER(16));
TYPE t_detalle IS TABLE OF
r_registro INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
FUNCTION f_totalizar_detalle(p_clave NUMBER)RETURN t_detalle;
END pkg_contabilidad;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_contabilidad AS
B_detalle t_detalle;
i integer :=1;
FUNCTION f_totalizar_detalle(p_clave NUMBER) RETURN t_detalle IS
    v_detalle t_detalle;
    CURSOR c_facturado IS 
    SELECT c.cod_rubro, 'H', CASE WHEN SUM(d.gravada)=0 THEN SUM(d.iva) ELSE SUM(d.gravada) END
    FROM fn_documentos_det d JOIN fn_conceptos c ON d.cod_concepto = c.cod_concepto
    WHERE d.clave_doc=p_clave
    GROUP BY c.cod_rubro;
    
    CURSOR c_datos IS
    SELECT SUM(d.total_doc), 'D',r.cod_rubro 
    FROM fn_documentos d JOIN fn_cajas_ctas r ON d.num_caja_cta = r.num_caja_cta
    WHERE d.clave_doc = p_clave
    GROUP BY r.cod_rubro;
BEGIN
    open c_datos;
    LOOP
    FETCH c_datos INTO v_detalle(1);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_datos;
    FOR fila IN c_facturado LOOP
    i := i + 1;
    v_detalle(i) := fila;
    END LOOP;
END;
END PKG_CONTABILIDAD;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a `pkg_contabilidad.t_detalle`, so the test needs to be:

```
declare
    resultao pkg_contabilidad.t_detalle;
    numero   number := 100;
begin
    resultao := pkg_contabilidad.f_totalizar_detalle(numero);
end;
```

It doesn't work in SQL because `pkg_contabilidad.t_detalle` is a PL/SQL type, not a SQL type (`create or replace type`). The database can perform some automatic conversions, but there are still limitations.

By the way, this loop will never complete because it lacks an `exit` condition:

```
open c_datos;
loop
    fetch c_datos into v_detalle(1);
end loop;
close c_datos;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a PL/SQL table type, with a table of a PL/SQL record type, which is defined in your package, which plain SQL doesn't know about and can't display - hence your invalid datatype error. If you need to call the function and access the data from SQL you can create schema-level object and collection types instead.

In your anonymous block you are a declaring a *new* record type. That looks the same to you because the structure is the same, but Oracle expects the exact type the function returns. That makes your test code shorter and simpler though. But you are also trying to return the whole collection into a single record.

```
DECLARE 
    l_detalle pkg_contabilidad.t_detalle;
    l_registro pkg_contabilidad.r_registro;
    l_idx pls_integer;
    numero NUMBER :=100;
BEGIN
    l_detalle := pkg_contabilidad.f_totalizar_detalle(numero);
    l_idx := l_detalle.FIRST;
    WHILE l_idx is not null LOOP
        l_registro := l_detalle(l_idx);
        -- do something with this record
        dbms_output.put_line(l_registro.tipo);
        l_idx := l_detalle.NEXT(l_idx);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8fe35db8fc39bf1ab7f510004c8e95bd) with dummy cursors.

Your function is a bit strange and probably isn't doing quite what you want; but also has two fatal problems: it isn't returning anything, and it has an infinite loop. I've fixed those for the fiddle but not anything else, as this seems to be an exercise.